# Select all months between 2 dates and repeat the result for each year

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression

I need to generate a list of months between 2 dates and then repeat the result for each year that i have with **SQL Server 2012**.

Here's an example:

- StartDate = 2010-11-01
- EndDate = 2011-01-01
- ReferenceYear = 2008

The result i want:

```
StatDate     StatYearGroup
--------------------------
2007-11-01            2008
2007-12-01            2008
2008-01-01            2008
2008-11-01            2009
2008-12-01            2009
2009-01-01            2009
2009-11-01            2010
2009-12-01            2010
2010-01-01            2010
2010-11-01            2011
2010-12-01            2011
2011-01-01            2011
```

I can generate the list of months between 2 dates with that query but how can i repeat the result for each year between @endDate and my @referenceYear? And also how can i get the StatYearGroup value?

```
declare @startDate date = '2010-11-01';
declare @endDate date = '2011-01-01';
declare @referenceYear int = 2008;

with dateRange(StatDate) as 
(
    select @startDate
    union all
    select dateadd(month, 1, StatDate)
    from dateRange 
    where StatDate < @endDate
)
select StatDate
from dateRange
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE 
      @startDate DATE = '2010-11-01'
    , @endDate DATE = '2011-01-01'
    , @referenceYear INT = 2008

;WITH rng AS 
(
    SELECT StatDate = @startDate, StatYearGroup = YEAR(@endDate)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, StatDate), StatYearGroup
    FROM rng 
    WHERE StatDate < @endDate
), years AS 
(
    SELECT StatDate, StatYearGroup
    FROM rng 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, -12, StatDate), StatYearGroup - 1
    FROM years 
    WHERE StatYearGroup > @referenceYear
)
SELECT *
FROM years
ORDER BY StatDate, StatYearGroup
```

Comment: The result is not good. The StatDate are always in 2010 and 2011 for each StatYearGroup. It should list them in 2007-2008, 2008-2009, 2009-2010, 2010-2011.